# Pattern match of scala list with generics

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

I have a class

```
case class MyClass[T](values: List[T])
```

and I'm trying to create a function which will return a value based on the type of T

```
def myFunc: T = values match {
  case v: List[Boolean] => false
  case v: List[MyType] => MyType.defaultVal
  case _ => throw new Exception("unsupported type")
}
```

However, I get compilation errors:

> Expression of type Boolean doesn't conform to expected type T
>
> Expression of type MyType.defaultVal.type doesn't conform to expected type T

I guess I can solve this by creating an abstract class ans subclasses, but I'd rather not do it this way. Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it with scala's [type tag](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) but I'm not an expert in that field, always found this too complicated.

A simpler solution I like to use is to pattern match on the head's element:

```
def myFunc: T = values.headOption.map {
  case v: Boolean => false
  case v: MyType => MyType.defaultVal
  case _ => throw new Exception("unsupported type")
}.getOrElse(throw new Exception("unsupported type"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that pattern matching is performed mostly at runtime and types are resolved at compile time. Because of type erasure `case v: List[Boolean] => ???` is not better than `case v: List[_] => ???`. In the line `case v: List[Boolean] => ...` compiler doesn't know that `T =:= Boolean`. Pattern matching can't return different types from different cases.

So you can either pattern match with type tags and casting

```
case class MyClass[T](values: List[T]) {   
  import reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}
  def myFunc(implicit typeTag: TypeTag[T]): T = values match {
    case v: List[Boolean] if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Boolean] => false.asInstanceOf[T]
    case v: List[MyType]  if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[MyType]  => MyType.defaultVal.asInstanceOf[T]
    case _ => throw new Exception("unsupported type")
  } 
}
```

or do this more type-safely with a type class (or polymorphic function)

```
case class MyClass[T](values: List[T]) {
  def myFunc(implicit myFuncInstance: MyFunc[T]): T = myFuncInstance(values)
}

trait MyFunc[T] {
  def apply(values: List[T]): T
}
object MyFunc {
  implicit val booleanMyFunc: MyFunc[Boolean] = new MyFunc[Boolean] {
    override def apply(values: List[Boolean]): Boolean = false
  }

  implicit val myTypeMyFunc: MyFunc[MyType] = new MyFunc[MyType] {
    override def apply(values: List[MyType]): MyType = MyType.defaultVal
  }
}
```